# maven-deploy-plugin ignores configuration block inside plugin execution

Tags: maven, deployment, plugins, configuration

I am trying to give parameters to the maven-deploy plugin from inside the pom.xml, but maven does not recognise the presence of the comfiguration block.

What am I doing wrong?

**I have tried:**

- moving the configuration block outside the executions block
- run without the goal

Given the following **pom.xml** part:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>assembly</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                        <finalName>xxx</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>make-assembly</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-deploy</id>
                            <phase>none</phase>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>deploy-file</id>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <file>xxx.zip</file>
                                <repositoryId>xxx</repositoryId>
                                <groupId>xxx</groupId>
                                <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
                                <version>xxx</version>
                                <url>xxx</url>
                                <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                                <packaging>zip</packaging>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

**1. Deploy with the :deploy-file:**

```
mvn clean deploy:deploy-file -Passembly -DskipTests -Drevision=1.2.3
```

**Result:**

The parameters 'file', 'url' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file are missing or invalid

**2. Deploy without the deploy-file:**

```
mvn clean deploy -Passembly -DskipTests -Drevision=1.2.3
```

**Result:**

Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter

**2. Deploy without the deploy-file:**

```
mvn clean deploy:deploy-file -Passembly -DskipTests -Drevision=1.2.3 -Durl=asdhasld
```

**Result:**
Maven recognised the url parameter.

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of maven-deploy-plugin and not most recent ones https://maven.apache.org/plugins/?

Comment: same with the latest

Comment: I would suggest to remove the whole part with maven-deploy-plugin in your profile or even completely .. because via `mvn deploy` you would deploy based the binding of maven-assembly-plugin the zip archive as well while everything like `mvn verify` will execute everything but not the deploy... So why so complicated?